# how to fix python script (email-listener)

Tags: python, gmail, imap

I have two python script to do listener on gmail to get incoming emails but when I run it I am gotten a following error any help will be welcome.
also if anu other script will be welcom
Already thanks.
the first script:

```
import email_listener

# Set your email, password, what folder you want to listen to, and where to save attachments
email = "example@gmail.com"
app_password = "password"
folder = "Inbox"
attachment_dir = "/path/to/attachments"
el = email_listener.EmailListener(email, app_password, folder, attachment_dir)

# Log into the IMAP server
el.login()

# Get the emails currently unread in the inbox
messages = el.scrape()
print(messages)

# Start listening to the inbox and timeout after an hour
timeout = 60
el.listen(timeout)
```

the output error:

```
C:\Users\PC Sony>"C:/Users/PC Sony/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe" "c:/Users/PC Sony/Desktop/elzero/elzero/import email_listener.PY"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\PC Sony\Desktop\elzero\elzero\import email_listener.PY", line 11, in <module>
    con.login()
  File "C:\Users\PC Sony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\email_listener\__init__.py", line 83, in login
    self.server = IMAPClient('imap.gmail.com')
  File "C:\Users\PC Sony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 254, in __init__
    self._imap = self._create_IMAP4()
  File "C:\Users\PC Sony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imapclient\imapclient.py", line 288, in _create_IMAP4
    return tls.IMAP4_TLS(self.host, self.port, self.ssl_context,
  File "C:\Users\PC Sony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imapclient\tls.py", line 44, in __init__
    imaplib.IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port)
  File "C:\Users\PC Sony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 202, in __init__
    self.open(host, port, timeout)
TypeError: open() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

the second script:
got it from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59538076/13780184)

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\Users\PC Sony\Desktop\elzero\elzero\import imaplib.py", line 68, in <module>
        result, data = server.uid('fetch', uid, '(RFC822)')  # fetch entire message
      File "C:\Users\PC Sony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 890, in uid
        typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, command, *args)
      File "C:\Users\PC Sony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 1230, in _simple_command
        return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
      File "C:\Users\PC Sony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\imaplib.py", line 988, in _command
        data = data + b' ' + arg
    TypeError: can't concat int to bytes
```

Comment: I tested first script and it works without problems on Linux Mint 20, Python 3.8. Maybe it is problem only on Windows, or only in Python 3.9

Comment: I tested with `Python 3.9` and it gives error. Maybe they changed something in `imaplib` and `email_listener` has problem. As I know `Python 3.9` is very fresh version so better use little older `3.8`. You can also send this problem to author of `email_listener` and maybe it will fix it in next version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`email_listener` works on `Python 3.8` but not on `Python 3.9`

I found that `email_listener` uses module `IMAPClient` which has problem with new `IMAP_SSL.open()` in standard module `imaplib`.

On page `IMAPClient` you can see

> Python versions 2.7 and 3.4 through 3.7 are officially supported.

so you have to use `Python 3.8` and wait until `IMAPClient` fix it.

Comment: i switched to 3.8 its work fine, only one last thing i got this error i think is related to decoding, any help or must creat a naw question